# PHP replace all dots to comma

Tags: php, regex

I have string

10.2, 200.3, 33.00

and I want it to be replaced as

10,2, 200,3, 33,00

I tried

`preg_replace("/[.]$/","/\d[,]$/",$input);`

but it is not replacing!

I can't use `str_replace` because it's task in university

Comment: why not use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: `$` means end of subject, and is of no use here.

Comment: this should be simple, you really shouldn't even need a regex for just replacing '.' with ','

Comment: @aaronman and how does your comment help OP?

Comment: It doesn't, his question is dumb, that's why this is a comment not an answer

Comment: _“I can't use str_replace because it's task in university”_ − so they are trying to make people more _stupid_ at your university …? :-p

Comment: If you're learning this stuff at university and you're stuck, why can't you ask your tutor? Stackoverflow may give you a direct answer to the question at hand, but the tutor's job is to help you understand it, which is what you actually need.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/\./', ',', $input);
```

This would replace all `.` dots with `,`.

```
preg_replace('/(\d+).(\d+)/', '$1,$2', $input);
```

This is more specific to your need. `$1` replaces first digit as in parenthesis; `$2` replaces second.

Comment: Use literal dot (i.e., \.) in second expression

Answer (score 15):

Do not use regular expresion when dumb `str_replace()` suffices:

```
$str = str_replace('.', ',', $str)
```

See docs: http://php.net/str_replace

Comment: I like how you called str_replace dumb! Maybe he is using using regex for a different reason.

Comment: @DavidChen that is something op should come out clear with(and i hope he does)..as it stands from the question and example,the answer in its current form is correct

Comment: I cant use this, this is my task in university

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9\s]/', ',', $input)
```

but it is better if you use

```
str_replace('.', ',', $input)
```

as Marcin answered.